# Tastypie ApiKey Authentication not working for foreman/heroky

Tags: django, api, curl, heroku, tastypie

I have an api that requires ApiKey authentication. If I am running this api using manage.py runserver locally it works just fine but if I am using foreman start both locally and deployed to heroku it gives the following error

```
{
"error_message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'", 
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/Users/carlosbalderas/.virtualenvs/recommenu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/carlosbalderas/.virtualenvs/recommenu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 435, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/carlosbalderas/.virtualenvs/recommenu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 453, in dispatch\n    self.is_authenticated(request)\n\n  File \"/Users/carlosbalderas/.virtualenvs/recommenu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 536, in is_authenticated\n    auth_result = self._meta.authentication.is_authenticated(request)\n\n  File \"/Users/carlosbalderas/.virtualenvs/recommenu/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/authentication.py\", line 197, in is_authenticated\n    except (User.DoesNotExist, User.MultipleObjectsReturned):\n\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'\n"
```

I am using these curls to interact with my api
(runserver)

```
curl -H "Authorization: ApiKey USERNAME:APIKEY" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/
```

(foreman)

```
curl -H "Authorization: ApiKey USERNAME:APIKEY" http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/user/
```

(heroku)

```
curl -H "Authorization: ApiKey USERNAME:APIKEY" http://fancy-name.herokuapp.com/api/v1/user/
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When checking in the shell the user is there. The same database is being used in each case.

Comment: Hi Carlos Balderas, did you find the solution to this? I have the same problem. It works in machine A, but fails on machine B with the same version of django, python and tastypie

Comment: I did not, I've since switched to Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a slightly older post but I just found the solution (for me anyway).

The solution was to move the API Key signal ([described here](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication)) into a signals.py file in my application's main directory.

The issue was that Tastypie was getting the username field via User.USERNAME_FIELD. If you have created a custom user, or if for some reason the django.contrib.admin.get_user_model method does not return correctly tastypie will default to a username field of "None".

Here's the code (from tastypie's compat.py):

```
    try:
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
        User = get_user_model()
        username_field = User.USERNAME_FIELD
    except ImproperlyConfigured:
        # The the users model might not be read yet.
        # This can happen is when setting up the create_api_key signal, in your
        # custom user module.
        User = None
        username_field = None
```

Since I was setting up the api key signal inside my models.py file, the get_user_model method was not returning correctly and tastypie was defaulting back to username_field = None.